# Disable form fields until a previous field has been filled with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript; can we set the other textfield to be dependent to the first or previous textfield?

For example, if we have a first name and surname field, I want to disable the surname field until a value has been entered for first name.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with javascript

Comment: There is a reason you have gone 0 for 5 with your question asking. You need to put a little more effort into researching the topic and clearly defining your problems here.

Answer (score 1):

I made a fiddle you can look at:  http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/7bkrn/2/

It's not perfect, but it will give you something to play around and practice with.  If you leave the "First Name" field without filling it out, it locks the "Last Name" field.

If you want to use JQuery, this is one way to do the javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $("#first_name_field").focus();

     var error_message = "Please add first name.";

      $("#first_name_field").blur(function() {
          if ($(this).val() != '')
          {
              $("#surname_field").removeAttr("disabled");    
              $("#message").html("");      
          }
     else {              
              $("#surname_field").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
              $("#message").append(error_message);      
          }         

      });
 });​
```

If you plan to use validations (which you should) than you should look at a plugin called JQuery Validation - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

I just made a quick one here to show you one way to do it.

Comment: No problem - if this solves your problem, feel free to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Could the same thing be done without javascript such that the html5 validation of the field triggered the revealing of the next field?

Answer (score 0):

try with this code.

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onkeyup="check()" />
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" disabled="disabled"  />
```

JavaSCript

```
function check() {
if(document.getElementById('fname').value != "")
    document.getElementById('lname').disabled = false;
else
    document.getElementById('lname').disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: You can use onblur event, that would make less calls.

Comment: Could the same thing be done without javascript such that the html5 validation of the field triggered the revealing of the next field?

Answer (score 0):

Already. You can use "readonly" property of "input" html tag and "onChange" event (for example) with JavaScript. This is only client side functionality. Don't use php for this purposes).